# What does a "with" statement do without the "as"?

Tags: python, dearpygui

```
with dpg.window(label="Window"):
    dpg.add_text("Hello, world")
    dpg.add_button(label="Save")
    dpg.add_input_text(label="string", default_value="Quick brown fox")
    dpg.add_slider_float(label="float", default_value=0.273, max_value=1)
    dpg.add_color_picker(label="Pick", default_value=(0, 0, 0))
```

This code runs without error (given the correct imports and setup)

```
dpg.window(label="Window")
dpg.add_text("Hello, world")
dpg.add_button(label="Save")
dpg.add_input_text(label="string", default_value="Quick brown fox")
dpg.add_slider_float(label="float", default_value=0.273, max_value=1)
dpg.add_color_picker(label="Pick", default_value=(0, 0, 0))
```

This code does not. A runtime error occurs on line 2. I do not understand how a with statement with no as affects the contents of the with. I've seen another  similar post, but I can't understand how the explanation answers my question.

Here is the stacktrace for the error:

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\18328\PycharmProjects\sandbox\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    dpg.add_text("Hello, world")
  File "C:\Users\18328\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\dearpygui\dearpygui.py", line 7019, in add_text
    return internal_dpg.add_text(default_value, label=label, user_data=user_data, use_internal_label=use_internal_label, tag=tag, indent=indent, parent=parent, before=before, source=source, payload_type=payload_type, drag_callback=drag_callback, drop_callback=drop_callback, show=show, pos=pos, filter_key=filter_key, tracked=tracked, track_offset=track_offset, wrap=wrap, bullet=bullet, color=color, show_label=show_label, **kwargs)
SystemError: <built-in function add_text> returned a result with an error set
```

Comment: `A runtime error occurs on line 2` then you should share the stacktrace here

Comment: The same thing as a with statement _without_ the `as`, except it doesn't give you a reference to the context manager. If you have a specific problem, we need a [mre] that lets us reproduce it when run _without any changes whatsoever_. Even `import dearpygui.dearpygui as dpg` would be help, because it tells people what library they need to install before they can run your code.

Comment: Not all [context managers](https://realpython.com/python-with-statement/) return a value at all; they're still performing whatever setup and teardown actions they need to.

Comment: Anyhow -- if you want to answer this _in the context of dearpygui_, you'll want to read its source code. If it's using something like thread-local storage or shared globals that the context manager manipulates, you'll see it there. The context manager's `__enter__` and `__exit__` handles are arbitrary -- they can do anything in theory, so when you ask this only as a Python question instead of a dearpygui question there's not a lot of room for a specific answer.

Comment: A very rough explanation of context managers is they can run some set-up and tear-down code before and after running the code in the indented block.  So it's not the same as just calling a function and using or discarding the return value

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Minor correction: With the `as`, it gives you a reference to whatever the context manager's `__enter__` *returns*. For many things (e.g. file-like objects) this will be the object `__enter__` is called on, but not necessarily; it could be some entirely unrelated object.

Comment: `with X` calls `X.__enter__()` (and arranges for `X.__exit__()` to be called when control flow leaves the `with` block). `as Y` binds the return value of `X.__enter__` to Y. You can study the behaviour yourself by creating and using your own context manager.

Comment: PEP-343 provides a [translation](https://peps.python.org/pep-0343/#specification-the-with-statement) of a `with` statement to "simpler" Python code. ("Simpler", in the sense that it would behave identically in a version of Python that lacks `with` statements in their grammar.)

Comment: Have a look at the src code: https://github.com/hoffstadt/DearPyGui/blob/8207351eafb7d3d549791ca1cbac4e586bb080da/DearPyGui/dearpygui/dearpygui.py#L2749 ...the code before the `yield` statement runs before your indented block ... it's using this decorator https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager so if you just call the function what you get back is a ContextManager instance without the `__enter__` code having run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Python side: Context managers run *completely arbitrary* code on enter and exit. Python doesn't force that code to do things "behind your back", but neither does it present them from doing so; so the implementation of the specific context manager at hand needs to be inspected to know *why* it's modifying behavior.

From a DearPyGui perspective: The C++ library that dpg backends into maintains a "container stack". Entering a container as a context manager ensures that it's on the top of your stack. When you create a new DearPyGui object that needs to be attached to a container, it refers to that stack, and attaches itself to the thing that is currently on top.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [translation](https://peps.python.org/pep-0343/#specification-the-with-statement) provided by PEP-343, you can see that

```
with dpg.window(label="Window"):
    ...
```

is equivalent to

```
mgr = dpg.window(label="Window")
exit = type(mgr.__exit__)
value = type(mgr).__enter__(mgr)
exc = True
try:
    try:
        ...
    except:
        exc = False
        if not exit(mgr, *sys.exc_info()):
            raise
finally:
    if exc:
        exit(mgr, None, None, None)
```

You can compare the above to the fuller translation in PEP-343 to see the single line I omitted that results from the use of `as`.

---

In your examples, `dpg.window(label="Window").__enter__` is called in the first example, but not in the second.